# Best practices for accessing ruby instance variables

Tags: ruby

David Black’s “Well-Grounded Rubyist” provided an example to illustrate the use of the `cycle` method:

```
class PlayingCard
    SUITS = %w{ clubs diamonds hearts spades }
    RANKS = %w{ 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A }
    class Deck
        attr_reader :cards
        def initialize(n=1)
            @cards = []
            SUITS.cycle(n) do |s|
                RANKS.cycle(1) do |r|
                    @cards << "#{r} of #{s}"
                end
            end
        end 
     end
end

deck = PlayingCard::Deck.new
```

I wanted to access the instance variable `@cards` defined inside a sub-class. What is the best method to access this array?

My understanding is that I would have to add an instance method in `Deck`. Is there a better technique?

What would be the best way to assign hands of cards?

Comment: Accessing from where?

Comment: What would be best to use the @cards array to define random hands of cards?  Should that be from inside the class Deck (or PlayingCard) or is that function best done outside and then reference the class?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can already access it now, because your script calls `attr_reader :cards`:

```
my_deck = PlayingCard::Deck.new(10)
my_deck.cards
```

`attr_reader` is a "class macro" (as Paolo Perrotta referred to this pattern in his "Metaprogramming Ruby" book) that simply defines a getter to an ivar with the same name:

```
# this line...
attr_reader :cards

# ... is equivalent to 
def cards
  @cards
end
```

Now, if you really wanted, you could pierce the object's veil and access directly its instance variables with `instance_variable_get`:

```
my_deck.instance_variable_get(:@cards)
```

But try to avoid this if possible to keep your objects well encapsulated.

Comment: A small point: Ruby doesn't have macros. [Module#attr_reader](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) is class method, so it's best to refer to it as such.

Comment: Thank you.  Using the @cards array to define hands of cards can then be used separately, correct?

Comment: In addition to Cary's point, `attr_reader` is not defined (in the OP's script), but an attribute reader is defined using the `attr_reader` method.

Comment: Cameron, not sure what you mean by saying "using the @cards array to define hands of cards". The "definition", or should I say allocation of cards is done in the `initialize`. Meaning, when you do `PlayingCard::Deck.new(10)`, the `initialize` method is called on the newly created instance, which populates the array pointed by the `@cards` ivar inside that instance. You can then access that `@cards` array through the `cards` method which is dynamically defined for you by the `attr_reader`. If you want a new deck of cards, you need to call a `PlayingCard::Deck.new` again to get a new instance.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you for the patience.  I tried this and now have a better sense of the example.